# Explanation of pair of intersecting lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation:
$x^2-y^2-2y-1<=0$

The exercise is the inequality, and, using wolfram, I understood that the equations is a pair of intersecting lines. I don't have a clue about what intersecting lines, in equation forms: how can I know it? What passages need I to do to tranform the equation into a pair of intersecting lines?

Comment: You sure that inequality is what interests you?

Comment: Yes, the exercise is the inequality, but i would like to know why the equation is 2 lines! Or other way to solve it..!

Comment: Please make this more informative. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Tried to edit it a bit, sorry for my english

Comment: Hint: $x^2-y^2-2y-1=x^2-(y+1)^2=[x-(y+1)][x+(y+1)]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2-y^2-2y-1=x^2-(y+1)^2=(x-y-1)(x+y+1)$, so the equation $x^2-y^2-2y-1=0$ represents the reunion of the two lines $y=x-1$ and $y=-x-1$.

Now if you are interested in the inequation $x^2-y^2-2y-1\le0$, it is equivalent to $x-y-1$ and $x+y+1$ being of opposite sign.

$x-y-1\ge0\iff y\le x-1$, the solutions are in the half plane **under** the line.

$x+y+1\ge0\iff y\ge -x-1$, the solutions are in the half plane **above** the line.

So the solutions are in the reunion of the region above both lines and the region below both lines.